# Requests Post does not take data

Tags: html, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a simple request post that is not taking the parameters set by "data" when I prettify the html it shows none of the data parameters were implemented. "xpp" should be 5, "xf1" should be 4, and "xf5" should be 1. I have tried changing "data = " to "files = " , and html rendering. I get 200 response, what am i doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {"xpp": 5, "xf1":4,"xf5":1}
url = 'http://spys.one/en/anonymous-proxy-list/'
r = requests.post(url, data = data, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `User-Agent` and use `https` for the URL

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0'
}

url = 'https://..........'
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```